# UIScrollView not staying with size classes

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I have a `UIScrollView` in a xib that has the size classes and auto layout set on.

The scrollview has some dynamically generated buttons added in a method, however, I can't get the scrollview to stop bouncing back to the top when the finger is released. The layout was working prior to size classes.

Various StackOverflow answers say I need to set the size of the scrollview to match the content while others say I need to have `TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` set (sorry, using Xamarin.iOS).

If I have the TranslatesAutoresizing set to true, the entire view breaks. Setting the scrollview to match the content still results in the bounce. The xib has the following set on the scrollview : show vertical indicator, scrolling enabled, paging enabled, direction lock enabled, bounces, bounces zoom, delays content touches, cancellable content touches.

Am I missing something?